# In a hive table, I have a coul

Tags: hive, split

I have a hive table in the following form with more than 100000 rows with the first column containing groups, with varying number of rows per group.

```
Column 1 Column 2
 A          a1
 A          a2
 B          b1
 B          b2
 B          b3
 B          b4
 C          c1
 C          c2
 C          c3
....
```

I wish to split the data into multiple columns as below.

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column4  Column 5
 A          a1      a2
 B          b1      b2       b3      b4
 C          c1      c2       c3
....
```

so on. 
Can someone help me with the query?

Answer (score 0):

there.

I am not sure how are you going to get #Columns of the destination table (although there are 5 of them in your example). I think you can turn to define the result schema as:

`column_1 string, column_2 list`

You could follow the example Chapter 13 of "[Programming Hive](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023555.do)" and implement a UDAF (source code is [here](https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/hive-collect/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jointhegrid/udf/collect/GenericUDAFCollect.java)). After compile and package the code into a jar (say, collect.jar).

- `add jar file:///home/.../target/collect.jar;`
- `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collect as "com.jointhegrid.udf.collect.GenericUDAFCollect";`
- Create the tablein your example `create table collecttest(str1 string, str2 string)`
- `load data local ...`
- `SELECT str1, collect(str2) FROM collecttest GROUP BY str1;`

Result:

```
A       ["a1","a2"]

B       ["b1","b2","b3","b4"]

C       ["c1","c2","c3"]
```

What's more, you can also select out 'column' value as you want. For example:

`SELECT str1, collect(str2)[1] FROM collecttest GROUP BY str1;` gives out result:

```
A       a2
B       b2
C       c2
```

`SELECT str1, collect(str2)[2] FROM collecttest GROUP BY str1;` gives out result:

```
A       NULL
B       b3
C       c3
```